# Swift NSAttributeType

Tags: objective-c, swift

Is there any way to convert the NSAttributeType to AnyObject. As per the documentation, UInt is a type of NSNumber hence a object. However, when I am trying to go through the below code its throwing me error.

```
    var predicateArray: [AnyObject]!;

    var initialDictionary = [String: AnyObject]()
    initialDictionary["displayName"] = "firstName"
    initialDictionary["identifier"] = "classCode"
    initialDictionary["rightExpressionType"] = NSAttributeType.StringAttributeType
    initialDictionary["modifierType"] = "NSDirectPredicateModifier"
    initialDictionary["operators"] = [NSPredicateOperatorType.EqualToPredicateOperatorType, NSPredicateOperatorType.NotEqualToPredicateOperatorType]
    initialDictionary["options"] = 0

    predicateArray.append(initialDictionary)
```

The error occurs at rightExpressionTypeKey and operators saying NSAttributeType and NSPredicateOperatorType cannot be assigned to AnyObject.

Could anyone please clarify on the same.

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `UInt` is value type, which is implicitly convertible to `NSNumber`, so it can be treated as `AnyObject`.
- `NSAttributedType` is an `enum` which is value type with `UInt` raw values, but not implicitly convertible to NSNumber.

To make your code work, you can use `.rawValue`:

```
initialDictionary["rightExpressionType"] = NSAttributeType.StringAttributeType.rawValue
initialDictionary["operators"] = [NSPredicateOperatorType.EqualToPredicateOperatorType.rawValue, NSPredicateOperatorType.NotEqualToPredicateOperatorType.rawValue]
```

Comment: Thanks @Jakub.The Solutions works. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @user3162384 please mark the solution as answered, so we know what the solution is.